# square of square root C++

Tags: c++, fractions

I'm doing a mixed number calculator for my c++ class. We are to store everything in a custom mixed number class with whole number, numerator and denominator. Because of this, irrational answers have to be approximated before converting to mixed numbers. My problem is if I square the output of 2^(1/2), it would return a mixed number that is really close to 2 but not 2 exactly. I want to know is there a way to make (a^(1/n))^n return a for all positive a's. TIA.

Comment: Are you using floating point numbers to represent the data?  If so, that's where the imprecision is coming from.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @BrianCain He explicitly said that he was using rational numbers.  (But of course, `2^(1/2)` has no exact solution over the set of rational numbers.  Which is his problem.)

Comment: @JamesKanze, he did say that he was using rational numbers but did not say what the representation in-memory was.

Comment: @BrianCain And what does "store everything in a custom mixed number class with whole number, numerator and denominator" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you understand that the square root of two is not a rational number. Hence there exist no two integers whose quotient squared is exactly two. You have two basic options:

1. You can round all results that are really, really close to an integer to that integer exactly. In some cases, this will give the wrong answer. But you should already have accepted that you can't always provide an exact answer to every possible problem because you're representing as rational some numbers that cannot be represented exactly that way.
2. You can add some additional information in addition to the two integers to the representation. For example, if something is a result of raising an integer to a power, you can flag it as such. If it is later exponentiated, you can employ rounding as above or you can just restore the original integer.

Basically, decide what you want and code it.

Comment: I had the impression of the possibility of achieving this was because many of the scientific calculators are able to return a for (a^(1/n))^n. Now I see the way they are able to do this is by using flags instead of other mechanism I was not aware of. Thank you for clearing it up for me.

Answer (score 0):

It that would have been possible for whatever kind of expression, we would have a "automatic theorem prove".

But unfortunately it has been demonstrated that the proving of a theorem is not an MT-decidable problem.

What you can do is provide some symbolic representation of frequently used expression (Note that a rational number is a symbolic representation of `a/b`), for example for `a^b`, `exp(a/b)`, `log(a/b)` etc. than expression combination and algorithm to simplify well-known combinations.

So 2^(2/2) will be 2 after expression simplification.

The result will be a quite complex code, not necessarily fast, that works only for the cases for wich you supplied the "solution".  But there always be a way to write an expression in a convoluted way you didn't predict.

At that point you have to accept in any case the limitation of a finite representation. Rational or floating-point whatever it is.